# Running Java keytool command from node on Windows

Tags: node.js, keytool

I'm trying to automate the creation on a keystore using Java. I'm running the child_process spawn function. For one thing, the keytool command response through the stderr channel which is odd, but it prompts me for the password. I'm unsure how to submit anything. If I call stdin.end() it kills the process.

```
var KEYTOOL_COMMAND = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_05\\bin\\keytool";
var ktArgs = ["-genkey", "-v", "-keystore", "test.keystore", "-alias", "test", "-keyalg", "RSA", "-keysize" ,"2048", "-validity", "10000"];

var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var cmd = spawn(KEYTOOL_COMMAND, ktArgs);
cmd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

cmd.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
cmd.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  cmd.stdin.write("password\\n\\r");
});

cmd.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Here I'm to submit "password" as my password.

Comment: You're escaping your CR and LF, try this instead: `cmd.stdin.write("password\r\n");` You might also try without the CR: `cmd.stdin.write("password\n");`

Comment: You should write an answer my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're escaping your CR and LF, try this instead: `cmd.stdin.write("password\r\n");` You might also try without the CR: `cmd.stdin.write("password\n");`